# Remove matching sample utterances in Alexa skill

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

I was submitting a skill to Alexa and it failed the certification process. One of the reason being,

> Two or more intents in your skill include the same sample
>   utterance(s). To ensure that user requests are routed to the proper
>   intent, please make sure each of the skill’s intents has its own
>   unique sample utterances.

Now, I have to go through every intent and check whether any utterance is repeating or not. But there are nearly 20 intents in my skill with many sample utterances and it is not possible for me to check every utterance manually.

Is there any easy way to remove the duplicate sample utterances in Alexa?

Comment: Code would be helpful.

Comment: You can do one thing, copy your JSON schema and take it as input. Iterate over sample utterances, create a hash, and then print the one which is duplicate. You can find the duplicates as well as where they have been duplicated.

Comment: I did the same. Thanks. @NikhilWagh

Comment: When you design your VUI make sure that you don't have any conflicting utterances.